# can you help me set up Firebase with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android Studio and Firebase. I am trying to build a test app linked to my Firebase database. I followed all the instructions.

I copy-paste this in the main Java activity in the oncreate method.

```
// Write a message to the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

     myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

I run the app and everything seems to work fine.
My question is: what is it meant to do exactly?
Where does the msg go and where am I supposed to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the shared code, if the `setValue()` operation doesn't fail, then you'll be able to see the "Hello, World!" message as the value of the `message` node. Your schema should look like this:

```
db
|
--- message: "Hello, World!"
```

Remember, that it is always a good practice to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something went wrong.

How can you see the above result, either in the Firebase Console or programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I see nothing in the console. Nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: I finally managed! But I changed something in my online database. The first database I had made had a way to insert tables and fields. Now I get an xml file! I am a bit confused but I did manage to write to the Firebase database

Comment: Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: yes it helped. I can now write data somehow ... but no clue on how to retrieve it. I read the official guide and there's almost nothing there. Even when I copy-paste what's in there it gives me errors.

Comment: Regarding reading data, give it a try, and if something doesn't work the way you expect, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.